# substring matching and indexing json fields in Postgres

Tags: json, postgresql

I have a JSON column in a PostgreSQL database (defined as `json JSONB NOT NULL`), and I want to search for specific keys with values containing a string (substring matching). I am flexible on how to form the json to achieve this, and here are two possible variations (`option1` and `option2`:

```json
{
  "option1": {
    "key1": [
      "value123",
      "value321"
    ],
    "key2": [
      "value234"
    ]
  },

  "option2": [
    {
      "key":"key1",
      "value": "value123"
    },
    {
      "key":"key1",
      "value": "value321"
    },
    {
      "key":"key2",
      "value": "value234"
    }
  ]
}
```

The search I want to achieve is to get me rows that have a JSON object with `"key1"` as the key and the value containing `"23"`. The key is always an exact match but I want to enable substring matching on the values.
Formulating the query is one part of the problem, which I could figure out, but indexing this for fast retrieval is where I am mainly lost and need help.

So far, we were doing exact matching, and our workaround was to flatten the JSON to a string array like `["key1:value123", "key1:value234", "key2:value234"]` and was using `SELECT * from T where T.json->'field' ?| array['key1:value123']` on a `gin ((json -> 'field'))` index. The new substring matching requirement on the value field no longer works with this approach and needs to remodel both the json structure and the indexing definitions.

Comment: You won't find a good solution. You should normalize the data model and avoid JSON. Then it can be done.

Comment: So you need to support arbitrary keys, or only those two specific keys?

Comment: @bergi arbitrary keys that we have no control on

Comment: One idea for indexing was to have two indices, one for keys and a separate one where I concatenate all the values in a big string. This way I could filter the rows that match in both indexes, and do additional checks if the match was from the same json object, which is not ideal but should reduce the solution space. But, was looking for a better solution than that before I try it

Comment: It just came to me: would it work if I used the existing flattened array and did searches like/like "key1:%23%" ?